# fancybox.js lightbox won't open in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I've got the standard fancybox lightbox (http://fancybox.net/) working on my website, and it works find with all browsers except for MS Edge. In Edge, when I hover the mouse over the thumbnail image, the cursor starts flickering and changing from "pointer" to standard. The lightbox modal opens only once on double-click, then only after a refresh of the page.

I am initializing the fanybox as follows:

```
jQuery(".fancy").fancybox({
    'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
    'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
    'speedIn'       :   600, 
    'speedOut'      :   200,
    'autoSize'      :   false,
    'maxHeight'     :   600
});
```

and this is how I implement the images:

```
<a class="fancy" rel="group" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="MYIMGSRC">
<img class="galimg" src="MYIMGSRC"> 
</a>
```

Could anybody lead me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Chris

Comment: try using `display: inline-block` OR `display: block` for your `<a>` tag

Comment: what are your CSS settings for the classes `fancy` and `galimg`?